# Go function that creates matrix with desired dimensions and values skips over every other index

Tags: arrays, go, matrix

i'm trying to write a function that creates a matrix where the user can input the dimensions of the matrix as well as the values in it. I managed to get a result but i notice that when it comes to inputting the values the function ignores one of every two indexes and fills it with 0. I'm wracking my head but it doesn't make sense to me...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func makeMatrix(n int, m int) [][]int {
    matrix := make([][]int, n)

    for i := range matrix {
        matrix[i] = make([]int, m)
    }
    fmt.Println("Enter elements : ")
    for i := range matrix {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &matrix[i])
        for j := range matrix[i] {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(matrix)
    return matrix
}

func main() {
    var (
        n, m int
    )
    fmt.Println("Number of lines : ")
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    fmt.Println("Number of columns: ")
    fmt.Scan(&m)
    makeMatrix(n, m)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line & it should work as you expected.

`fmt.Scanf("%d", &matrix[i])`

You are already doing Scanf on `matrix[i][j]` which will read each iteration of `i` & each iteration of `j` - you don't need to read/Scanf on `matrix[i]`.

Comment: Did it and it just changed the ignored indexes from pair ones to odd ones...

Comment: @ObnoxiousPotato Not clear with your comment - Check this https://go.dev/play/p/F5dQCsp9QCY if it makes sense.

Comment: What i meant is if choose a 3x3 filled with only 1, with the original code it returns [101][101][101], with your version it returns [010][101][010]. As for the playground version, while it does work it takes away the whole user inputting the parameters side of the program. Still, thanks for the reply

Comment: @ObnoxiousPotato Here is the output when I run that code go.dev/play/p/F5dQCsp9QCY in my machine. https://ibb.co/yFSrcRk I tried with value 1 and it filled as well appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, i finally understood what to keep in the code to make it work, took me a while!